# Restkit - Matching a Path with ? and =

Tags: restkit, sockit

I've set up a response descriptor like this:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:exhibitMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"?json=exhibits/get_exhibits" keyPath:@"d.exhibits" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

And made the request like so:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"?json=exhibits/get_exhibits" parameters:nil success:
```

But I get this error:

```
2014-03-17 11:14:39.856 MuseumMap[6135:60b] E app:ExhibitTableViewController.m:49 Load failed with error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0x8fb69f0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://exhibits.wpengine.com/?json=exhibits/get_exhibits, NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL 'http://exhibits.wpengine.com/?json=exhibits/get_exhibits', which failed to match all (1) response descriptors:
  <RKResponseDescriptor: 0x9480270 baseURL=http://exhibits.wpengine.com/ pathPattern=?json=exhibits/get_exhibits statusCodes=200-299> failed to match: response path '?json=exhibits/get_exhibits' did not match the path pattern '?json=exhibits/get_exhibits'., NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded., keyPath=null, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://exhibits.wpengine.com/?json=exhibits/get_exhibits, NSUnderlyingError=0x8fb6990 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."}
```

My thought is that there is a problem matching because of either the ? or the = in the pathPattern but I've tried escaping those and it doesn't seem to make a difference. Anyone have any ideas why this wouldn't match? The error message being `response path '?json=exhibits/get_exhibits' did not match the path pattern '?json=exhibits/get_exhibits'.` seems a bit off.

Comment: `?` is a special character in regex. If you place this after any character, then it means 0 or 1 time occurrence. You have to escape the `?` with escape character. Usually it is `\?`. Not sure what it is in your case!

Comment: Tried that, didn't work either. Thanks.

Comment: Thats not a regex is it?

Comment: It's listed as a "pathPattern". There isn't much explanation of it on their site, that I found.

Comment: If its a regex, just use `.+` to debug it.

Comment: A regex with `?` that does not quaqntify anything, whould throw an error stating that.

Comment: It isn't a regex. It's a pattern used by https://github.com/NimbusKit/sockit I'm not sure you can use query parameters in the path pattern though...

Comment: Seems like you're right, the query params don't work in sockit. Going to use user-friendly permalinks as a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the way the URL was formed. I changed my site to use permalinks instead of the ?json query parameters and that seemed to work. The path matching eliminates the query parameters before it matches so those cannot be used to match in restkit.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#1.1.-Requests

Comment: Hello! Looks like I have similar problem. Could you please tell how to use permalinks instead of ? json queries?